# Cython ndarray with arbitrary dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm writing some Cython code that needs to be able to handle NumPy ndarrays that have an arbitrary number of dimensions. Currently, I just have different functions that accept ndarrays of different sizes, sort of like:

```
def func1(np.ndarray[DTYPE_float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
    # Do something with the 1-D ndarray.

def func2(np.ndarray[DTYPE_float64_t, ndim=2] arr):
    # Do something with the 2-D ndarray.

def func3(np.ndarray[DTYPE_float64_t, ndim=3] arr):
    # Do something with the 3-D ndarray.
```

But I would like to write a single generic function that takes an ndarray of arbitrary dimension as an argument. I tried simply leaving the "ndim" argument off, but then Cython assumes ndim=1, and that's no good.

Is there a way to do this, or do I just have to write one function for each number of dimensions?

Answer (score 5):

If you're just looking to do something elementwise, the trick is to just do get a 1D view of the array and operate on that

```
def func(arr):
   shape = arr.shape
   output = _func_impl(arr.ravel())
   return output.reshape(shape) # ensure that the output is the same shape
       # as the input. Skip this if it doesn't make sense!

def _func_impl(np.ndarray[DTYPE_float64_t, ndim=1] arr):
   # do something useful
```

Comment: Good point. But can we flatten a memoryview inside cython? For example, I have a function `cdef foo(float[:,:] arr)`, and I want to apply the elementwise function on `arr`, so I need to flatten it into just 1dim.

Comment: Not easily I think - you could probably go through a pointer but it wouldn't be "nice". (Note that it'd only work on `float[:,::1]` C contiguous memoryviews - other memoryviews would need reallocating the memory, which is definitely outside the scope of a memory __view__). It might be worth making a feature request on Cython's issue tracker if there isn't one already there

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually after playing with Cython a bit, I think I may not go ahead with Cython now, because compared to the numpy code I have, Cython doesn't seem to be able to run much faster at all, besides I still want to reuse the numpy broadcasting functions inside Cython, which makes it impossible to release GIL, and further making it impossible to run the Cython code in parallel.